# Borrar una fila de base de datos sql desde python con numero unico

Tags: python, mysql

Estoy realizando un control de stock en el cual a cada producto lo ingreso con un numero único con el que consigo seguir en detalle la localización de cada producto. Estoy utilizando SQL como base de datos y Python para hacer tanto la interfaz grafica como el monitoreo de los productos.
Para esto cree una variable en python "numeroIdentificacion" la cual le da un valor unico a cada producto y en la base de datos cree una columna con el nombre "ID"
El problema viene cuando tengo que dar la baja del producto.
Para eso estoy utilizando este codigo:

```
DELETE FROM Productos WHERE ID=numeroIdentificacion
```

Al compilar me arroja que hay un problema en la sintaxis.
Necesitaría al ejecutar el codigo eliminar la fila en la cual corresponda el numero de id

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega el bloque de código donde pones esa sentencia delete.

Comment: La sintaxis parece correcta, ¿pero que hay alrededor? Como dice @Marcos Guerrero, añade el bloque de código, a ver si hay algo que le afecte.